Unwinding Stack on Cortex-M with FreeRTOS: Handling Interrupts and Stopping Conditions
I am writing an unwinder for a Cortex-M (an ARM processor) running FreeRTOS. It mostly works, and I can trace the stack in many cases, but I have encountered a few issues that I haven't been able to resolve.

Unwinding After an Error Interrupt:
I need to unwind after an error interrupt to retrieve the call trace. I've noticed that several registers are pushed between the address indicated by the frame pointer (FP) and the address where the next frame pointer is located. I don't know how to determine the offset to retrieve the next frame pointer (and the link register, LR, for backtrace). The number of pushed registers varies between compilations, likely due to optimizations.
The offset between the two frame pointer

Stopping Condition for Unwinding:
When I hardcode the starting address, the unwinding seems mostly correct, but I am unsure when to stop the unwinder. I suspect it should stop at the program's entry point, which I can retrieve in some way. However, in practice, it seems like it should stop when LR = FP. This is based on my observations, and I would appreciate any authoritative sources or explanations on this topic.
Successfull unwinding by hand


I tried to use libgcc's _Unwind_Backtrace function with the compilation flag -funwind-tables but it does not work great. So I decided to write the unwinder on my own :

unwind.h
#define CALL_STACK_SIZE 10u

// TODO : Change the registers to use an array for r0-r3
typedef struct {
    uint32_t r0;
    uint32_t r1;
    uint32_t r2;
    uint32_t r3;
    uint32_t sp;
    uint32_t lr;
    uint32_t pc;
    uint32_t xpsr;
    uint32_t cfsr;
    uint32_t hfsr;
    uint32_t call_stack[CALL_STACK_SIZE];
} savedRegisters_t;


unwind.c
savedRegisters_t IN_CORE_DATA_SECTION saved_registers = {0};

void IN_CORE_TEXT_SECTION SaveCallStack() {
    volatile uint32_t* call_stack_ptr = saved_registers.call_stack;

    volatile uint32_t lr = 0;

    volatile uint32_t fp = 0;

    volatile uint32_t i = 0;

    // Restore the `fp` value before the entry in `SaveCallStack` function from interrupt handler. (I don't know why is the offset 24 but it works)
    // Warning /!\ : maybe it is compiler dependent)
    __asm volatile (
        "add %0, r7, #24"
        : "=r" (fp)
    );

    do {
        if (i == 1) {
            // The same code as when `i` != 1 but with a different offset (hardcoded but this need to change to fit ARM interrupt logic)
            __asm volatile (
                "ldr r0, [%1, #12]                  \n" // 12 is the offset that is hardcoded when i == 1
                "mov %0, r0                         \n"
                "ldr r1, [%1]                       \n"
                "mov %1, r1                         \n"
                : "=r" (lr), "+r" (fp)
            );
        } else {
            __asm volatile (
                "ldr r0, [%1, #4]                   \n" // Get LR at [FP] + 1
                "mov %0, r0                         \n" // Save LR into `lr`
                "ldr r1, [%1]                       \n" // Get the new FP
                "mov %1, r1                         \n" // Set it into `fp`
                : "=r" (lr), "+r" (fp)
            );
        }

        // Save lr into the array of `saved_registers`
        call_stack_ptr[i] = lr;

        i++;
    } while (i < CALL_STACK_SIZE && fp != lr);
}

Any insights or references on these issues would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Have you compared your implementation to some other projects like https://github.com/red-rocket-computing/backtrace and https://github.com/armink/CmBacktrace  and https://github.com/OPEnSLab-OSU/FeatherTrace
